# How can you add an item to an array with RESTful calls?

Tags: json, angular, rest, angular-httpclient, json-server

I'm using Angular HttpClient to make restful calls to json-server. I have an object with a string id and an array of objects. I would like for the user to be able to add more of these objects to the array. I'm using the date in ISO format as the id.

I guess I could get() the array, update it in typescript, and then post it. This seems like 2 calls when it should just be one.

I've tried all types of post(), put(), and patch() giving it all types of things. Arrays, objects, etc. I've tried googling "how to add item to array with restful" and it seems like this isn't a thing. Am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

**JSON object**

```
{
      "id": "2020-05-08",
      "logs": [
        {
          "id": "Log title",
          "time": "12:00"
        },
        /* I want to add another object here */
      ]
}
```

Comment: think your object name is item then just `item.logs.push({"id":"yeni","time":"13:00"});`

Comment: Yes that works in javascript/typescript. I'm trying to do it with a restful call

Comment: Subscribe to the API call and then on success you can add it to your array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Like with a Subject?

Comment: it seems you want to do an update right? if yes, first you need to provide just the id and the object to add, second, in backend fetch by the provided id  then construct your new object finally do an update

Comment: Say you have a collection at `http://localhost/api/logs`.  REST with a GET will retrieve a list, POST *a single item* would add it to the list...  What api are you using?